# Django "add" Template Tag when variable may be empty

Tags: python, django, templates, addition

I am wondering if it is possible to use django's `add` tag to add two queryset objects, when one may or may not be empty depending on the instance.  I have seven different queryset totals that I want to total up, and some may be empty at different times.  Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to write a long if statement or do it in the view?

Comment: It is best to do this in your view. Adding too much logic to your template code never ends well.

Comment: Maybe you can do an `{% if var1 and var2 %} {{ var1|add:var2 }}`?

Comment: Or an easier way to do in the views would be loop through the specific value you want to add in each queryset, if it exists, add to a global variable and then pass that variable through the context to the template

Comment: Thank you, I think you were right.  I used pandas in my views to manipulate the data and was able to easily get a total to render on the template.  I appreciate the input.